# exec command in bash doesn't work when calling a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exec

The following are two shell scripts stored in the same folder with execute permissions on both:

shell1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
exec shell2.sh
```

shell2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
```

When trying to execute shell1.sh I am getting the following error:

```
./shell1.sh: line 3: exec: shell2.sh: not found
```

Is there something I am doing incorrectly? This works in other machines though but just in one particular server its not working.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The current dir is not part of your PATH.
Try

```
exec ./shell2.sh
```

Comment: I figured out the problem, the server where it was working had . in the path which meant the current directory was always in the path. Thanks for you input.

Comment: Fix it correctly, by being explicit (like this or more so), and remove "." from the path on that server!

Comment: Can you accept this answer? Btw, Chris means: A dot in your path is dangerous, better remove it on the other server.